# Loop repeating scanf and printf

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf

I've written a program that will `scanf` twice before `printf` and will output two of what should be a single `printf`. The issue seems to begin occurring from the point that asks the user to input a number between 1 to 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days.

I'm not sure what's causing this double inputs and outputs and the occasional delays. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int i;
    int limit;
    int day[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int high[10], low[10];

    printf("---===IPC Temperature Analyzer V2.0===---\n");

    printf("Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    while (limit <= 2 || limit >= 11) {
        printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("Day %d - High: ", day[i]);
        scanf("%d", &high[i]);
        printf("Day %d - Low: ", day[i]);
        scanf("%d", &low[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDay Hi Low\n");
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf("%d   %d    %d\n", day[i], high[i], low[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (high[max] < high[i])
            max = i;
        if (low[min] > low[i])
            min = i;
    }

    printf("\nHighest temperature was: %d on day %d\n", high[max], day[max]);

    printf("Lowest temperature was: %d on day %d\n", low[min], day[min]);

    int n;

    do {
        printf("\nEnter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature "
               "for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit:");
        scanf("%d\n", &n);

        while (n > 4) {
            printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 4, inclusive: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
        }

        while (n < 0) {
            printf("Goodbye!\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        float avgSum = 0.0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            float avgOfDay = (high[i] + low[i]) / 2.0;
            avgSum += avgOfDay;
        }
        float overallAvg = avgSum / n;
        printf("The average temperature up to day %d is: %.2f\n", day[n - 1], overallAvg);

    } while (n > 0 || n < 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit:5
5
Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 4, inclusive: Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 4, inclusive: 3
The average temperature up to day 3 is: 2.50

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: 2
2
The average temperature up to day 2 is: 2.75

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: -1
The average temperature up to day 2 is: 2.75

Enter a number between 1 and 4 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit: -1
Goodbye!
```

Comment: Your question will be clearer if you give the expected output and the *exact* actual output.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my post with an example of the issues that are occurring.

Comment: Note that spelling consistency is very desirable in programmers — it's crucial with variable names, and good inside messages (`temeprature` --> `temperature`).

Comment: Since `exit()` doesn't return, the loop `while (n < 0) {
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    exit(0);
    }` would be better written as an `if` statement: `if (n < 0) {
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    exit(0);
    }`.  It isn't part of your current problem, though.

Comment: this line: `} while (n > 0 || n < 4);` allows ANY number to be acceptable.  Perhaps you meant: `} while (n > 0 && n < 4);`  however, that only allows values 1,2,3  Suggest: `} while( n>0 && n <=4)`

Comment: this line: `while (n < 0) {` has the problem that the code will never actually loop.  Suggest using: `if (n < 0) {`

Comment: this line: `float avgSum = 0.0;`  is assigning a `double` value to a `float` variable.  Perhaps you meant: `float avgSum = 0.0f;`  <-- note the addition of the trailing `f`

Comment: this line: `float avgOfDay = (high[i] + low[i]) / 2.0;` is dividing by a `double` suggest: `float avgOfDay = (high[i] + low[i]) / 2.0f;` so dividing the float values by a float literal

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are describing can be traced to the `scanf()` statement at the beginning of the `do` loop:

```
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
```

The newline at the end of the format string is the trouble. When `scanf()` encounters a white-space character in the format string, it matches white-space characters in the input stream until a non-white-space character is encountered. The problem is that when you press the enter key to input your number, this is just another white-space character, so `scanf()` greedily continues waiting for more input, until either a non-white-space character, or `EOF` is encountered. When the user enters a non-white-space character at this point, the `scanf()` white-space match fails, the entered character remains in the input stream, `scanf()` finally returns to the calling function, and at last, the next `scanf()` picks up the character that was just rejected. This is the cause of the sporadic response that you observed.

The fix for this is simple. Just remove the `\n` from the end of the format string. It is usually the case that a white-space character at the end of a format string is the wrong thing to do.

There are other issues in the code. The test at the end of the `do` loop should be:

```
while (n > 0 && n < 4);
```

The test for an exit value would be better as an `if` statement instead of a `while` loop, and the test should be for `n < 1` instead of `n < 0` to avoid a division by zero error:

```
if (n < 1) {
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
        exit(0);
}
```

It seems that you should change the input prompt to:

```
printf("\nEnter a number between 1 and 3 to see the average temperature for the entered number of days, enter a negative number to exit:");
```

If the user chooses `4` here, but only entered data for 3 days, the calculation will access uninitialized values in the `high[]` and `low[]` arrays. You will also need to change this input loop to:

```
while (n > 3) {
            printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 1 and 3, inclusive: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
        }
```

There may be other issues, but this should get things running.

Answer (score 1):

`while (n > 0 || n < 4);` => `while (n > 0 && n < 4);`

Comment: Code-only answers are not that helpful, and this does not address the problem that OP is reporting. Some explanation for what your proposal fixes would be good, and with some further digging into the actual problem reported by OP you could turn this into an actual answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling, Thank you for your suggestion. I'm new to stackoverflow and my English isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the solution to my problem. The new line function next to the scanf and printf of some parts of my code were causing the program to reiterate certain scanf and printf functions.

```
scanf("%d\n", &n) => 
printf("%d", &n)

printf ("The average temeprature up to day %d is: %.2f\n", day[n-1], overallAvg); =>  
printf ("The average temeprature up to day %d is: %.2f", day[n-1], overallAvg);
```